# Will ASP.Net 4.0 website work on new server which supports only ASP.Net 4.8 framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I have an old website which was developed on .Net Framework 4.0 and client wants to move this website to new server which supports .Net 4.8 Framework.

I am afraid if website will work properly on .Net 4.8 framework as i am not sure if there is full backward compatibility.

Unfortunately i cant test it as i don't have access to new server.

My understanding is it should work and i should point framework to 4.8 in below line of cide in web.config
`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" >` i hope rest will work such as `<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design......` as all of them point to 4.0

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <!--  assembly doesnt work on MochaHost
     <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
     -->
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C" />
    <!---->
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: "Unfortunately i cant test it as i don't have access to new server" - but surely you can provision a machine (virtual or not) with .NET 4.8 installed, can't you? That would at least provide a significant level of confidence.

Comment: I am planning to create a VM now so that test machine configuration is close to production server.. I had looked the at MS documentation but was in doubt best way to find out is to test it.. will ask client for server configuration so to setup VM

Answer (score 3):

.NET 4.8 is an 'extension' on .NET 4.0. Microsoft tries it's best to be backwards compatible, you can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.0-4.8 for seeing what can break if you run your website (or any other program compiled in .NET 4.0) on the .NET 4.8 runtime. Most breaking changes have a switch that you can return to the older behavior, see the link above.

You don't even have to change the target framework in the config. Changing the `<compilation targetFramework="4.8" >` will cause the website to be compiled under 4.8 (if it hasn't been pre-compiled) on the first request, which has it's own set of changes that can be viewed on the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.0-4.8.

In case of doubt, you can install IIS on a test computer or your local computer, configure the website and test before you release on the new server.

Comment: I am planning to create a VM now so that test machine configuration is close to production server.. I had looked the MS documentation but was in doubt best way to find out is to test it..